# String was not recognized C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert this `string` to `DataTime`, I have tried `ParseExact` but with no success.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", "14/04/2014 14:26:53", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 5):

14 isn't a valid month. Is your `MM/dd` backwards?

Comment: It's backwards if you're from one of those _weird_ countries that puts the month first :P

Comment: @Simon: I think you got that backwards. And I don't get those middle-endian countries either. YMD and DMY are reasonable, MDY is just weird.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You've got your format and string the wrong way around. Also, as @Matti Virkkunen said, 14 and 04 are around the wrong way. Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("04/14/2014 14:26:53", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got the parameters backwards. First the date, then the format.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "14/04/2014 14:26:53", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have swapped the date string and the format - the signature is `DateTime.ParseExact(string s, string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)`
2. As Matti noticed, your `MM/dd` part of the format is also swapped (when looking at the `14/4` part of the date string)